# Controlling Pi via PC through TightVNC

Tags: remote, vnc

I've set up everything to control my raspberry pi with TightVNC.
But as I try to connect I get an error: "Authentication reason: server is not configured properly". I'm sure I my password is right and everything and none of previously proposed solutions on other forums have helped.

Does anyone know how to fix this, or can come up with a good alternative for controlling my raspberry pi with a pc?

Thanks in advance for any help[image]

[image: The error I get:]

Answer (score 2):

Try another client or viewer. First, make sure you are starting the server on your RPi correctly. I found the documentation at http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md very helpful.

I also had problems with TightVNC. I had the server running and verified operation using a VNC session from my iPad. However, no configuration of address, session ID, or port number (5900 is the appropriate port would work). I'm sure that TightVNC works fine, but I couldn't figure it out from the available documentation or various forum posts.

Rather, I used the RealVNC Viewer (https://www.realvnc.com/download/get/1671/). This viewer worked without any issues.